# Is it possible to write PhD thesis (or PhD level article) in Computer Science without (real) advisor?

Tags: advisor, learning, distance-learning

**Is it possible to write PhD thesis (or PhD thesis level scientific articles) in Computer Science without real advisor (of course there always be formal one)?** E.g. there are (almost) no books how to learn musical composition, artistic painting, cello playing - all such learning is done during private tête-à-tête studies. Maybe Computer Science is similar discipline which can not be learned by self-studying books, articles and conference proceedings. Maybe Computer Science has enough unwritten folklore that is passed only via direct contact between advisor and student? I have read many acknowledgments in thesis that ascertain this viewpoins, there are so much thanks for explaining one or another thing.

My question is about having real PhD advisor. Of course, each PhD student has its advisor by the University rules but there may be cases when having advisor is mere formality, advisor can have no knowledge and skills and the discipline pursued by the student. It can happen and it happens in countries that are not top countries.

Comment: "...there are (almost) no books how to learn musical composition..." That's called music theory. Also, why would you have someone not in your field look at your dissertation? It's like asking a math professor to chair a literature student's committee.

Comment: Of course, there is music theory (with lot of books) - how to write down the composition, but there are almost no books on harmony, composition itself. E.g. Schoenberg or Messian books are rare exceptions.

Comment: Are you simply making a comment about differing levels of engagement of the adviser? Of course you're right--some advisers are overbearing, some are so "hands-off" that the student barely hears from them until the defense, and many reach a happy medium. I'm not surprised to hear the second is more common in lower-income countries. But is this a true question where you're seeking info from someone that you don't currently possess?

Answer (score 7):

Let's not lose sight of the fact that **doing a PhD is a very hard thing to do**, even *with* an adviser (and particularly in computer science, but also in essentially any other discipline). So what you're asking is basically "is it possible to do this thing that is difficult enough that a good proportion of the people who try to do it don't finish, but in a way that makes it even *more* difficult than it already is?"

To use an exaggerated metaphor, it is a bit like asking whether it's possible to climb mount Everest blindfolded. The *literal* answer is, [yes, it's possible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erik_Weihenmayer). The *practical* answer is: any specific person who tries it will almost certainly fail.

Answer (score 3):

> Possible? yes. But unnecessarily harder.

Going beyond what a good advisor can do to help you learn, publish stuff, and actually get your phd, he/she can greatly improve your chances of getting a job afterwards.

And yes, while there are several books available,  there are nuances and tricks that are passed mostly tete-a-tete. As is almost always the case. It really helps to have someone with experience backing you up.

Answer (score 1):

I disagree on

> Maybe Computer Science is similar discipline which can not be learned
>   by self-studying books, articles and conference proceedings.

You still can learn a lot by yourself. It may not be as good as if you have a mentor. But start from what you know the most (at the very minimum, the courses with top scores in your BSc. or MSc.), read the top publications in similar topics, and go from there.

I met a lot of successful Phd. students who are almost independent researchers from day one. A lot of successful professors also did Phd. independently.

If you have choice to go with helpful supervisor, then go. If you do not have, the only thing you can do is to try your best.

Comment: I wonder if those students instead relied on peers, mentors at other institutions, and faculty whose work touched on some aspect of (but not the core of) their work. In my non-CS experience, I had a low-usefulness advisor so I relied more heavily on other resources.